# Unable to inject dependencies of injected bean with Arquillian

Tags: jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian to inject the dependencies for my tests. It works OK if I inject the beans directly to my test class, but if the beans have dependencies of their own tht have to be injected, those dependencies do not get injected.

For example: the FacLptConfiguration bean gets imported correctly into my Test Class, but it does not get injected into the CfdFileCreator bean. I injected FacLptConfigurtion to the test class just to confirm that the injection works, but the user of this class is CfdFileCreator.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CfdFileCreatorArquillianTest {


@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDepolyment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class)
            .addClass(FacLptConfiguration.class)
            .addClass(InterimFileCreator.class)
            .addClass(CfdFileCreator.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addAsWebInfResource(new File("C:/aLearn/FacLpt/web/WEB-INF/env-entries.properties"));
}

public static String TEST_FOLDER = "C:/aLearn/FacLpt/src/test/testdata/pruebas/";

@Inject
private FacLptConfiguration facLptConfiguration;

@Inject
private CfdFileCreator cfdFileCreator;


@Test
public void createCfd() {
    System.out.println("in createCFD");
    cfdFileCreator.createCFDFile();
}
```

}

These injections are not working:

```
  @Singleton
  public class CfdFileCreator {


  @Inject
  private InterimFileCreator interimFileCreator;
  @Inject
  private FacLptConfiguration facLptConfiguration;
```

Answer (score 7):

I think your problem is the location of the *beans.xml*. For a web archive it should be *WEB-INF/beans.xml*. Use:

`addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, ArchivePaths.create("beans.xml"))`

See also https://community.jboss.org/thread/175404